Convert DateTime with TimeZone in Dart/Flutter
I just need to fetch DateTime to API with similar format  like this one "Tue Oct 15 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (Singapore Standard Time)". I used below code using timezone/timezone.dart and timezone/data/latest.dart package but no success.
  final currentDateTime = tz.TZDateTime.from(
      tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local).copyWith(
        hour: 0,
        minute: 0,
        second: 0,
        millisecond: 0,
      ),
      tz.local,
    );


Use intl as follow:
DateTime date = DateTime.now().toLocal(); // Get the current local date and time
  
  String timeZoneOffset = _formatTimeZoneOffset(date.timeZoneOffset);
  String formattedDate = DateFormat('EEE MMM d yyyy HH:mm:ss').format(date) + ' GMT$timeZoneOffset';

//helper function to get formatTimeZoneOffset
String _formatTimeZoneOffset(Duration offset) {
  final hours = offset.inHours.abs().toString().padLeft(2, '0');
  final minutes = (offset.inMinutes.abs() % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0');
  final sign = offset.isNegative ? '-' : '+';
  return '$sign$hours$minutes';
}


Great!, thanks Sukaina..
